# Connect ssh after reboot with port forwarding

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssh, portforwarding, autostart

I am trying to automatically connect server -> server on startup using ssh with port forwading. I need this so that the 1st server can connect to the 2nd sever's postgres DB.

For the connection I am using

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -L 5434:localhost:5432 user@ipAddress
```

This works fine when I try it manually and I can connect to my DB with

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5434
```

with having the .pgpass file in the home dir..

But the problem is, that the ssh connection is NOT made by itself on startup. I thought of using the sudo crontab's @reboot, but that did not work.. Then I tried to move the script to /etc/rc.local based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735935/running-command-at-startup-on-crontab) but also with no luck..

Please can someone help me establish the ssh connection on startup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved it by adding "-N" to the ssh connection parameters. This should keep it in background and it seems to be working..
So now I have

```
ssh -N -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -L 5434:localhost:5432 user@ipAddress
```

in the root's crontab and it connects after reboot. This does not solve the "cold start" connection, but since it is a server it will be mostly only restarted and not powered down and started..